# Win7 error: "CLR initialization failed with error 800700c1."

Tags: windows-7, powershell, windows-update, chocolatey

I installed and used [`chocolatey`](https://chocolatey.org/) in the past on my Windows 7 running in Parallels on Mac OSX.
However, recently, whenever I try to use it from the command prompt I get the following error:
`CLR initialization failed with error 800700c1.`

I don't think this is a problem with `choco` itself, but something with the CLR configuration.
I couldn't find any solution to this.

**UPDATE**:
I get the same message if I run `powershell`.
Also, when I attempted "Control Panel->Troubleshooting->Fix Problems with Windows Update" I get an error dialog with the same code.

I also tried repairing and updating the .NET Framework installation, but to no avail.

**Update 2**
I think it is related to the following DLL:   `C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC80.CRT_1fc8b3b9alel8e3b_8.0.50727.3053_x-ww_b80fa8ca\MSVCR80.dll`. It is apparently corrupted. When I try to open in in `depends` it gives an error: "No DOS or PE signature found. This file is not a valid 32-bit or 64-bit Windows module."

Comment: [0x800700c1](http://errlookup.azurewebsites.net/?err=0x800700c1) = "ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT" according to Winerror.h.  What have you tired already in attempts to repair it?  Have you tried reinstalling Chocolatey? Checked for disk/file-system corruption?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: Sorry. I added additional info from my ongoing fix attempts.

Comment: Do a `CHKDSK` to see if you have file-system corruption, once that comes up clean run `SFC /scannow` to ensure all system files are correct. Report back with results. :)

Comment: All return clean. `chkdsk: Windows has checked the file system and found no problems.` `SFC /scannow: Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.`

Comment: And the problem still exists eh?  Weird.  Have you tried in Safe Mode?  How about in regular mode, while logged in as a different User?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: Alas, same error with another user *and* in Safe Mode. I am truly baffled. BTW, might this be related to the fact that this Windows 7 is running under Parallels Desktop 10 for Mac (10.1.0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it fixed.

As I suspected, it was related to a (possibly) corrupt 64-bit DLL `MSVCR80.DLL`.

I uninstalled all the "Microsoft Visual C++ ***2005*** Redistributable" packages (both 32 and 64 bit) via the regular uninstall screen from the Control Panel - I had 3 such packages.
After this, everything returned to working order.

Comment: Can we get someone to mark this as the answer?

Comment: Gotta wait for a few more hours....